# django alternative to tiny tiny rss

Tags: python, django, rss, rss-reader

I love the [idea behind tiny-tiny rss](http://tt-rss.org/redmine/): it's lightweight, open-source, frequently updated, and [seems to work very well](http://www.linux.com/learn/tutorials/322446-weekend-project-replacing-google-reader-with-tiny-tiny-rss).  Furthermore, the client only needs a browser. I want to play around with the source code and customize it a bit, but I don't know PHP.  I was wondering, are there any django or python projects like tiny tiny rss?  I'm looking for a reader where the client only needs a web browser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Newsblur (https://github.com/samuelclay/NewsBlur) seems to be an appropriate choice: server side is based on python with django, celery and pymongo. MIT license.